# Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.8, fatal-error

If I press manage customers on the Magento backend I get this fatal error. Does anyone knows a fix for this?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
>   /home/vhosts/MYSITE/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.php
>   on line 514

Comment: Recompile under System > Compilation that could help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any custom modules? Try disabling them one by one and check if the error is resolved. It seems like a collection is being called but due to the missing class for the collection it is throwing the error.